# enhancing wadl with json and xml

Tags: java, json

I looked at [WADL in json in CXF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653318/wadl-in-json-in-cxf/23038404#23038404) but it doesn' work for me. So re posting here...

```
@Description("Service for reading books")
@Path("/bookService")
public interface BookService
{
    @GET
    @Path("/getBook")
    @Produces(
        {"application/xml",
        "application/json"})
    @Description("Get Book for a given id")
    public Book getBook(@QueryParam("bookId") Integer id) throws Exception;
}
```

On localhost:8080/services/?_wadl gives

```
<application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <grammars />
    <resources base="http://localhost:8080/services/">
        <resource path="/bookService" id="books.rs.BookServiceImpl">
            <doc>Service for reading books.</doc>
            <resource path="/getBook">
                <method name="GET" id="getBook">
                    <doc>Get Book for a given id</doc>
                    <request>
                        <param name="bookId" style="query" type="xs:int" />
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/xml" />
                        <representation mediaType="application/json" />
                    </response>
                </method>
            </resource>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</application>
```

Below is the service config for the service and what should be the json schema here to get the json representation of wadl

```
<jaxrs:server id="restContainer" address="/">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="bookService" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <bean id="jacksonJsonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.wadl.WadlGenerator">
                <property name="linkJsonToXmlSchema" value="true" />
                <property name="schemaLocations">
                    <list>
                    <value>classpath:/json.schema</value>
                   </list>
                </property>
                <property name="useJaxbContextForQnames" value="true" />
                <property name="ignoreMessageWriters" value="true" />
                <property name="addResourceAndMethodIds" value="true" />
            </bean>
            <bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider">
                <property name="serializeAsArray" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

I tried Try ?_wadl&_type=json for json and ?_wadl&_type=xml for xml

but i get  [#document: null] in response of above. Please suggest what is missing?

I see in the logs of server it says could not find resource with path classpath:/json.schema. I have put json.schema under web-inf folder. I know i am missing the path here but no idea how to put correct path.

Comment: Nope, what i need is when i say http://localhost:8586/learn-camel/services?_wadl then it shows me <representation mediaType="application/json"/> in response. I want to show what json or xml would be returned actually (some sample json). I am not able to find how to show this in wadl like wsdl.

Comment: When i did this, i can see wadl as json. What i want is the actual output of json should show my added json.schema file document under it. So when i give this wadl to third party then can find the expected output in json format or xml format from wadl itself.

Comment: Yes, So like wsdl, It can say what exactly input output it expects. So anyone has access to wsdl can find input and output. Similarly i want to know if there is any way i can achieve in wadl? My intention is not to convery whole wadl to JSON. My intention is in the request response in wadl, i want to show my sample json rather than simply wadl showing  <response><representation mediaType="application/xml"/><representation mediaType="application/json"/></response>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct path for json.schema, as you have configured it, is `WEB-INF/classes`.

To add example JSON or XML fragments in your WADL, you can use the @Description annotation. You are already using it, just extend the implementation.  You can put the whole lot in your java class using the syntax you already have, or you can dump the `value` property in favour of the [`docuri` property](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest-2.4.x/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/model/wadl/Description.html).

```
@Description(docuri = "classpath:/wadlDocs/getBookExample.txt")
public Book getBook(@QueryParam("bookId") Integer id) throws Exception;
```

Comment: Thanks. DO you know, how one can generate doc uri by extending wadlgenerator and handleRepresentation method?

Comment: Do you mean, how can you generate example document fragments?  No, I don't know how to do that, sorry.  Don't know if it's possible.  I use enunciate with Jersey, which does this for me.